# How can solve input value unique validation on multiple columns for Laravel-5.4

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel-5

I want to input value validate Unique With multiple columns value in Laravel 5.4

//set Validation Rule

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [            
    'dock_name' => 'required|unique_with:docks,zone_id'
]);
```

Show Error as:

*Method [validateUniqueWith] does not exist*

> [DB_Table:docks Index: ALTER TABLE `rdb`.`docks` ADD UNIQUE
>   `dock_zonid` (`dock_name`, `zone_id`)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `unique_with` which not correct you have to use `unique` for unique check.

Just read this [5.4/validation#rule-unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique)

Do like this

```
'dock_name' => 'required|unique:docks,zone_id'
```